# Question about the degree of the splitting field of $X^4-2X^2-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, splitting-field

I have one question regarding an exercise that I have done:

The exercise is the following:

For the following polynomial from $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, determine a splitting field in $\mathbb{C}$ and the degree of this splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$:
The Polynomial is $X^4-2X^2-2$

We have $X^4-2X^2-2=(X+i\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1})(X-i\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1})(X+i\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1})(X-i\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1})$ so we have that $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1},\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1})=:L$ is a splitting field.

So now comes my question, with the Eisenstein Criterium we can see that the polynomial is irreducible, so in my mind, since $L$ is the splitting field of a fourth degree irreducible polynomial, the degree must be $4$.

But this is not the case since: $(i\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1})^2 \in  \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1})$ and $i\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1})$ we have $[\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1},\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1})]=2$ and therefore $[\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1},\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1}):\mathbb{Q}]=2 \dot 4=8$

Since the polynomial is of degree $4$, is irreducible, and contains both $i\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}$ and $i\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1}$, couldn't we say that the minimalpolynomial of the extension $L$ should be of degree $4$ or lower? How then does $L$ have degree $8$ over $Q$?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065712/let-k-be-the-splitting-field-of-the-polynomial-x4-2x2-2-find-an-automorphis), why the degree is $8$. Why could we say that it is $4$? Consider an easier example with $X^3-2=0$. The degree of the splitting field then is $6$, and not $3$. In general it can happen that it is $n!$ for a polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ (as in the case $X^3-2$). And $n!$ is much bigger than $n$.